# CopyFiles not working in INF files

Tags: windows, inf

I've created this xxx.inf file and placed a Sample.exe alongside the same directory.

```
[Version] 
Signature=$CHICAGO$ 

[DestinationDirs] 
SampleCopy = c:\\Sample

[DefaultInstall] 
CopyFiles = SampleCopy 

[SampleCopy] 
sample.exe
```

I tried to install the inf file, the desktop refreshes but I don't see the creation of c:\sample folder nor the files that should be copied there

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[Destination directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547383(v=vs.85).aspx) need to be given in format "dirid,subdir", where [dirid is a number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553598(v=vs.85).aspx).

In your case you could use one of the two lines below.

```
SampleCopy = 24,\Sample
SampleCopy = -1,C:\Sample
```